# MVC3 Model binding in HTTP GET request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Without customization, can I do something like this in MVC 3?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult MyAction(ViewModel model)
    {
        // Do stuff
        return View("ViewName", model);
    }
```

The reason I am doing this is to pass data between different pages as part of a work flow.  (I.e. when user fnishes what's needed in step 1, pass the form data to step 2...)

Comment: With data from the querystring, like `?prop1=value1&prop2...`.

Comment: Why dont you store the form data in TempData in step 1 to pass in step 2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will work as long as you have the same parameter Name as of the Property name of your Model class

Assuming your class is like this

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public string Loc{ set;get;}
}
```

You can do a Get request like this

```
MyAction?Name=jon&Loc=America
```

Comment: Even though this *technically* works, say 1 of the fields on the ViewModel is a large collection `IList<SomeClass>` with 1000 records. Couldn't this violate/break the allowable length for a HTTP GET? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: @atconway the op wants the action method as it is (It is a GET method). If he comes across a situation where he has more data, he may change it. My answer is specific to the Op's situation in the question.

Comment: Yep I understand - I was just reading and thinking using the same technique but realized the request might get too large for a GET in my situation. As an aside and knowing the premise your answer was specific to OP, is it still true that a ViewModel value in querystring that is too big could cause an issue?

Comment: @Shyju This answer is true only if the members in the `ViewModel` class are all scalar properties. If one of the properties' type is a custom class with its _own_ properties, the values of that property won't bind. The two workarounds would be to make it a POST request or to name those properties in the GET request's URI string with dot notation (which I'll expound upon in my own answer). Because yours is the accepted answer, I think it would be beneficial to edit it to include this.

Answer (score 3):

Shyju's answer only works if the members of class in the endpoint's method signature contains only scalar properties. But what if you have nested classes? Let's assume that your `ViewModel` class looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Address MyAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And the `Address` class looks like this:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say the GET request was done via AJAX and you did something like this in JavaScript:

```
var address = {
  Line1: "123 Nowhere St.",
  Line2: "Apt. B5"
}
var getRequestData = {
  Name: "Joe",
  Title: "Manager",
  MyAddress: address
}
var uriString = $.param(getRequestData); //the parameters for the GET request
$.get("/ViewResult?" + uriString, function (data) { /*callback function*/ });
```

Even though the shape of your `address` object in JavaScript perfectly matches the C# `Address` class in the endpoint's method signature, the `Line1` and `Line2` sub-properties will ***NOT*** bind. Their values will come through as `null`.

There are two workarounds to this.

### Workaround 1:

The first is to use dot notation when naming the parameters in the GET request instead of nested JavaScript objects. Using this method, the GET request data in AJAX would look like this:

```
var getRequestData = {
  Name: "Joe",
  Title: "Manager",
  MyAddress.Line1: "123 Nowhere St.",
  MyAddress.Line2: "Apt. B5"
}
```

MVC model binding will know how to do this, as long as all your property names all match up (they are case-sensitive, so be careful).

If you're not using AJAX, but just a plain HTML form submit, it's even easier. Just name the input elements with that same dot notation. Razor syntax makes this really easy with helper methods like `TextBoxFor()`, but here's an example in plain HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="/ViewResult">
  <input type="text" name="Name" />
  <input type="text" name="Title" />
  <input type="text" name="MyAddress.Line1" />
  <input type="text" name="MyAddress.Line2" />
  <button type="submit">Submit GET request</button>
</form>
```

### Workaround 2:

The other way around this is to simply use a POST request instead of a GET. Beware that it's technically bad practice to perform a POST request without the intent of actually changing some data on the server side, but it is an option.

Answer (score 2):

For Web API 2:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get([FromUri]ViewModel model)
{
    // Do stuff
    return View("ViewName", model);
}
```

Comment: There isn't any `FromUriAttribute` in ASP.NET MVC5

Comment: Oh I meant Web API 2 I guess.

Comment: but, in that case, you should replace ActionResult returned type with the model type. And the View method

Answer (score 1):

You can do it; it will automatically bind any values in the query string to properties with matching names.

That said, it's not something that's generally done; it's the `[HttpPost]` method where you see the model binding performed, as the interfaces for the two actions need to be different somehow.  You can solve that by posting back to a different action name, but you may still trigger model validation errors on the (partial) load of the model, which would be really confusing to a user.

Answer (score 0):

You can post a form to a get by setting the `PostMethod` attribute to get. If the form's input fields match any of the accepting `ViewModel` then they will be filled. These matches are determined by the `name` field in an input (`<input name="MatchedField">` -> `public string MatchedField { get; set; }`).

What you should do is pass the form from a post, and then redirect to the get from the post action. This pattern is best practice and is known as the Post-Redirect-Get pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against this approach. Best solution to just use POST, because if you use GET, once you click back from step 3 to step 2 and the browser cache is not available, you will perform actions on an old version of the `ViewModel`. Is there a particular reason why you want to use GET?

Comment: Its bad practice to use "POST" when not making making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I can not suggest to use QueryString to pass values.
You can use one of below:
This code will render a partial view with the given model.Be sure you add model to your view. And your view should be placed in `Shared` folder

```
public ActionResult myaction(ViewModel model)
        {

            return PartialView("anotherView", model);
        }
```

Another way to do almost the same thing:

```
 public ActionResult myaction(ViewModel model)
        {
            return View("someAnotherView", model);
        }
```

if your view is not in the same controller , use the path for view name like `"../Controller/viewName"`

There is also a different approach which can be done by using TempData:

```
public ActionResult myaction(ViewModel model)
        {
            TempData["model"] = model;
            return RedirectToAction("someAnotherView");
        }
```

but you should reach your data in the view with the code as shown below:

```
   @{
    ViewModel model=(ViewModel)TempData["model"];

    }
```

Hope one of above helps..

Regards