# Pass a list of complex object in query string to WEB API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I have an WEB API method that uses `[FromUri]` to bind complex type object to my view model, and in this view model, I have a **list of complex object** inside it. How do I populate this list when I do a **GET** request?

This is my method from **WEB API**:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage ListPaged([FromUri]PaginationReParams parameters)
{
   // DO SOMETHING HERE...
}
```

The PaginationReqParams **view model**

```
public class PaginationReqParams
    {
        public PaginationReqParams()
        {
            this.Filters = new List<FiltersReq>();
        }

        public List<FiltersReq> Filters { get; set; }
        public Int32 Page { get; set; }
        public Int32 PageSize { get; set; }
    }
```

The FiltersReq class

```
public class FiltersReq 
    {
        public String Field { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }
        public String ComparisonOperator { get; set; }
    }
```

When I pass parameters to my query string Like "page" it binds normally, but how do I do to bind the "Filters" parameter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass the parameters like this:

```
?page=1&pagesize=10&filters[0].Field=name&filters[0].Value=aladdin&filters[0].ComparisonOperator=eq&filters[1].Field=age&filters[1].Value=18&filters[1].ComparisonOperator=eq
```

Comment: max URL length allowed is still 2,083 characters :)